How can I configure the channel Id as Opt_In?
I am sending this push notification to the Airship platform via PostMan.
I have this body:
{
    "audience": {
        "channel": [
            "XXXx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
        ]
    },
    "device_types": [
        "web"
    ],
    "notification": {
        "alert": "test 13:34",
        "actions": {
            "open": {
                "type": "url",
                "content": "xxx url",
                "defaultAction": false
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "title": "Test User",
            "icon": "xxxxx"
        }
    }
}

Authorization is bearer and OK. All browsers are configured OK and they receive this notification, including Safari on macOS.
Android works perfect, the problem is on iPhone which is not receiving the push notification. Airship support tells me I have to have the channel id as Opt_In, as Opt_Out is working for all browsers.
How can I configure the channel Id as Opt_In? It is necessary so iPhone can show the push notification. I can do this configuration via JavaScript if the solution is using SDK.
URL I am using is POST: https://go.airship.eu/api/push
